# How to get MVC Model Datatype String with Newline in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, string

I am attempting to pass the data (type = string) from my MVC model to a javascript funcion but I keep getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". I believe this is caused by the newlines in the model data as it only occurs with multi-line strings.

The idea is for the user to press the "undo" button/link to reset the text area.

Image:

[image]

CSHTML:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.updates[i].body, new { @Class = "txtTextArea floatLeft", @Id = "Edit_" + i.ToString(), @style = "width: 70%;", @Rows = "4", @Cols = "30" })

<a class="textRight EditToLink" onclick="clearInput('Edit_@i.ToString()', '@Html.Raw(Model.updates[i].body)')" id="EditToOneLink_@i.ToString()" href="#" >undo</a>
```

Javascript Function:

```
function clearInput(input, val) {
    if (document.getElementById(input) != null) {
        if (val != null) {
            val.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n");
            document.getElementById(input).value = val;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(input).value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Similar Question:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1741372.aspx?pass+model+parameter+to+javascript+function

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a `replace(@"\n", "")` on the string.

OR

Use JSON.NET `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.data)`

By the way, in CSS to display multiline stuff use this:

```
{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: The .replace didn't work for me, but the JsonCovert.SerializeObject worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch! cheers

Comment: Yeah, no worries, I tend to just stuff my entire view model into JSON and have knockout take care of the rest!

Comment: @Racksickle see the update about css, if that is of any use! I've recently worked a lot with multiline stuff in MVC 4 and HTML